# Inserting and displaying image as BLOB file in SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

This is how i creted my Database using sqlite

```
Pro:~ dd$ sqlite3 db.db
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table cus(id integer primary key, firstname varchar(30));
sqlite> inser into cus(firstname)values('f');
Error: near "inser": syntax error
sqlite> insert into cus(firstname)values('f');
sqlite> select * from cus;
1|f
sqlite>
```

Now i need to insert Images, i read that we could save images as `BLOB` files, Can someone show me how to save an image to a database file and retrieve the image and display in `imageview` ? A tutorial or sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off storing paths or relative paths to the files on disk in the database.  The filesystem is optimized for loading and storing blob data while a database is optimized for relational data to query on and store transactionally.

It allows you to keep your database small and light while you control the memory footprint of the images (and what you choose to cache and how).

Related posts:

[Android sqlite / BLOB perfomance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400540/android-sqlite-blob-perfomance-issue)

http://groups.google.com/group/alt.comp.lang.borland-delphi/browse_thread/thread/fdc16d03b613a00e

Comment: I'll have a look at the links so i could get an idea, but, i am doing this for iPhone.

Comment: the comparison is on file system vs sqlite blob.  I think it translates.  The thing that is slowing you down (storing blobs with the relational writes and reads) is in sqlite which is common to all platforms - especially those that are memory constrained like devices.