# Mysql, sqlite and blob datas, what is the good practice?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, blob

Good morning!

I'm currently creating an Android app that have a list of texts and show one randomly. I would like to update the list from a server and I don't know what is the best way to do that.
I plan to use an sqlite database in order to download only the new datas.
Since each text is associated with an image, I consider using Blob in my database, but I don't know if using blob is really a good practce.
Should I store the path to the images instead?

Comment: How long do you need to persist the data?

Comment: Once the data is stored, it mights stay for a long time and it theorically doesn't need to be changed

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400540/android-sqlite-blob-perfomance-issue

Comment: Thank you Hans, so Blob seems not to be optimized to store more than ~20kb data in an sqlite base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/30-53/MySQL-vs-SQLite

these two websites can give u a better idea which one to opt. !
Every aspect has been defined in these two sites. Hope i helped u there.

My suggestion:
Making use of JSON support in PostgreSQL is a benefit over other RDBM's
as it's fast.

Comment: Thank you! Here I read that PostgreSQL isn't fast for read operation, but I need low delays when I randomize. But JSON seems to be a good idea